# What does the number behind "synced?" mean?

Tags: iri-node, iota-network, node

If you go to https://field.deviota.com/ and check for the node "codepleb", you notice that the node is not synced, but there is some kind of number at the end (even if it might be synced at this point you look at it). What does that number mean? It looks like it's completed, but the sync status is still "no". What does this number mean, and why is it in the "x/y" format, when it actually is always "y/y" and therefore redundant?

This number is not field specific. It also existed back when I ran my wallet as full node with static neighbors.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You want those two nombers to be the same but they also need to be synced with the last Milestone issued by the Coordinator. We used to have a channel in Slack to see this number but I think it is no longer working since the migration to Discord (#botbox). You can check the list of nodes in [IOTA Dance Nodes](https://iota.dance/nodes) to see the milestone they are at (they will be a bit behing the last Coo Milestone but difference should not be that big).

Answer (score 0):

One number is "latest milestone index"
the other number is "latest solid milestone index"

see 
[What is the "latestSolidSubtangleMilestone"?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/1450/what-is-the-latestsolidsubtanglemilestone/1451#1451)

If both numbers are equal the node is synced. Currently it is as I checked your node codepleb.

YES
401140 / 401140

Comment: But they are always equal. Even if not synced. The number seems to vary. Thx for the link.

Comment: The numbers increase over time (higher milestone achieved). They are equal when in sync. Maybe it's an update problem with the web app